# External data from file throws error while using where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to read a text file with 2,000 values, but my where clause throws error.

```
    SELECT mac.mac_id,mac.mac,mac.mac_type,record.soc_id 
    from mso_charter.mac
    where record.soc_id in ('C:\Users\xyz\worldbox2_Prod_09-17-2017.txt')
    join mso_charter.record on mac.record_id = record.header_id;

    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "join"
    LINE 4: join mso_charter.record on mac.record_id = record.header_id;
            ^
    ********** Error **********

    ERROR: syntax error at or near "join"
    SQL state: 42601
    Character: 155
```

Comment: Where after join not before. So... from.. join...where.

Comment: Voting to close as simple typographical error.  (retracted) question is two fold fix error and how to I query a .txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT mac.mac_id,mac.mac,mac.mac_type,record.soc_id 
from mso_charter.mac
join mso_charter.record on mac.record_id = record.header_id
where record.soc_id in ('C:\Users\xyz\worldbox2_Prod_09-17-2017.txt');
```

and unless you have multiple soc_Id's

`where record.soc_id = ('C:\Users\xyz\worldbox2_Prod_09-17-2017.txt');`

Not this:

```
SELECT mac.mac_id,mac.mac,mac.mac_type,record.soc_id 
from mso_charter.mac
where record.soc_id in ('C:\Users\xyz\worldbox2_Prod_09-17-2017.txt')
join mso_charter.record on mac.record_id = record.header_id
```

Compilers are pretty picky about the order

- SELECT
- FROM
- JOIN
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- HAVING
- ORDER BY

Though order of execution is

- FROM
- JOIN
- WHERE
- GROUP BY
- SELECT
- HAVING
- ORDER BY

Comment: But are you sure about reading the text file this way ?My text file looks something like this 000001048A003CA9
000001048A003D62
000001048A003E03 seperated by next line each

Comment: oh maybe I missunderstood the question.  The text file isn't a string it's a text file that you're trying to see if record.soc_id exists in that file?

Comment: Yea, I am trying to get data from text file to the where clause where soc_id will be the data from text file

Comment: I would load the data into a table (temp or otherwise then join)  Here's how to load: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html and drop the table when done; or keep it around and reload/append when you get new files?